# Javascript library for converting MGRS to Lat/Lng

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system

Is there a JS library that converts MGRS to LL? I have found one that converts Lat/Lng to MGRS, but nothing that converts MGRS to Lat/Lng.

Someone asked this question in the past, but the answer was USNG to LL but I HAVE to do MGRS to LL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about usng.js from http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/40941-MGRS-to-lat-long-or-UTM-Conversion?

In the library's MGRS to LL function it states

> "create a Military Grid Reference System string.  this is the same
>   as a USNG string, but with no spaces.  space delimiters are
>   optional but allowed in USNG, but are not allowed in MGRS notation.  but the numbers are the same."

By that logic, presumably USNG to LL *is* MGRS to LL.

Comment: I should have said this a while ago. I forgot about the open question, but that is what I ended up doing.

Comment: link is 404, and could probably updated to https://github.com/codice/usng.js/

Answer (score 2):

Here are some NodeJS / Javascript packages I found on GitHub:

- https://github.com/beatgammit/node-coordinator
- https://github.com/proj4js/mgrs
- https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js